# Error: could not load library "libmbedtls.so" whilst installing BlackBoxOptim in Julia on Ubuntu Conda

Tags: julia

I've installed Julia in a fresh Conda environment in Ubuntu. It's a clean box.

I'm trying to install the Julia package BlackBoxOptim. Unfortunately, I'm met with an error concerning a missing libmbedtls.so file, when I `import BlackBoxOptim`:

```
julia> import BlackBoxOptim
[ Info: Precompiling BlackBoxOptim [a134a8b2-14d6-55f6-9291-3336d3ab0209]
ERROR: LoadError: InitError: could not load library "libmbedtls.so"
libmbedx509.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

...

ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile MbedTLS [739be429-bea8-5141-9913-cc70e7f3736d] to "/home/shodan/miniconda3/envs/julia_ness/share/julia/compiled/v1.9/MbedTLS/jl_1fTIaN".

...

ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile HTTP [cd3eb016-35fb-5094-929b-558a96fad6f3] to "/home/shodan/miniconda3/envs/julia_ness/share/julia/compiled/v1.9/HTTP/jl_PpFD0T".

...

ERROR: Failed to precompile BlackBoxOptim [a134a8b2-14d6-55f6-9291-3336d3ab0209] to "/home/shodan/miniconda3/envs/julia_ness/share/julia/compiled/v1.9/BlackBoxOptim/jl_ROSMVe".
```

I hope resolving the first error takes care of the rest.

Where do I find a copy of libmbedtls.so? Where should it live within my Conda environment (recall, it's a "clean box", therefore everything is a Conda and Ubuntu default)? And, is there a convenient way for Julia's package manager to retrieve the *.so file without my intervention?

**EDIT #1**

The missing libmbedtls.so belong to the Mbed TLS C library. I've installed it using the following:

https://mbed-tls.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/building/

Unfortunately, the error remains. Searching for the missing shared object (.so file), I found copies here:

```
/home/shodan/miniconda3/envs/julia_ness/lib/libmbedtls.so
/home/shodan/miniconda3/envs/julia_ness/lib/julia/libmbedtls.so
```

They exist. How do I get julia to point to them?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a known issue concerning Conda mixed with Julia. I won't try to go into the details because I'm not an expert either. The solution was to install Julia not via Conda but rather using Juliaup. These were my steps:

- Removing my old conda environment.
- Making a new conda (virtual environment).
- Installed Juliaup following the curl installation command line. See: https://github.com/JuliaLang/juliaup
- Reinitialised (exited and entered) my environment.
- Loaded Julia on the prompt.
- Then, inside the package management part of Julia: `add BlackBoxOptim`